# JSON response handling iOS 6

Tags: json, ios6, nsdictionary

I have a REST service that produces JSON results that has been verified by several different validation tools, etc.  I'm fairly new to iOS development, but not development in general.  I'm having some issues with extracting the objects/responses/anything from my response from the service.  Despite my best efforts, I've been unsuccessful with my attempts.

A typical response from the service:

```
[
    {
        "prcID": 547,
        "prcName": "walls",
        "prcDescription": "hi-lo",
        "1prc": 270,
        "2prc": 282,
        "3prc": 312,
        "4prc": 348,
        "5prc": 354,
        "6prc": 360,
        "7prc": 366,
        "8prc": 372,
        "9prc": 384,
        "10prc": 432
    },
    {
        "prcID": 548,
        "prcName": "doors",
        "prcDescription": "hi-lo",
        "1prc": 270,
        "2prc": 282,
        "3prc": 312,
        "4prc": 348,
        "5prc": 354,
        "6prc": 360,
        "7prc": 366,
        "8prc": 372,
        "9prc": 384,
        "10prc": 432
    }
]
```

The code is a mix of sample code and attempts by myself to make things work:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
    //parse out the json data
    NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions
                                                           error:&error];


    NSMutableArray *myarray = [json.description mutableCopy];
    outPutText.text = [myarray mutableCopy];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
        [NSURL    URLWithString:@"someserviceurl"]];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
```

This code lets me at least see the response from the service in a TextView, but each time I attempt to drill into the 'json' NSDictionary using either ObjectAtIndex or iterate using AllKeys I get a similar error as I do when I try the code below:

```
NSArray* somearray = [json objectForKey:@"prcName"];
NSLog(@"PriceName: %@", somearray);
```

The error is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71944b0'
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I realize that my question and code maybe riddle with obvious oversight-I've tried for hours to search and push through this, but I'm hitting a roadblock I just can't seem to push pass.  I appreciate any insight or suggestions as to even a portion of the issue.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
NSString *firstName = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                       @"%@",
                       json[0][@"prcName"], nil];
NSLog(@"%@", firstname);
```

iOS6 casts the response into an array, and I used `[0]` to select the first 'block' of the response JSON.